# Current user-issues in using features of Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Issues using features of VS2015 where if two users are connected to same VM(work station) concurrently and trying to access Visual studio 2015 (work station).

could you please explain that if 2 users are accessing same VM concurrently and trying to access Visual studio 2015 at same time with single license how it really works?

Comment: Is this not a support question that should be directed towards Microsoft not stack overflow?

Answer (score 0):

Licenses are normally tied to a specific user so if you have two users accessing VSTS they each need a valid license, no matter if they are using the same work station or not.

Comment: Could you please explain me how it works : if 2 users are accessing same VM concurrently and trying to access Visual studio 2015 at same time

Comment: If two user log in with the same credentials, it is really not two users, but just one. So it all depends on what you do. The license however is tied to a person so if you have two persons logging in with the same user you would be violating the terms of the license.